# Magento 2 API always returns Consumer is not authorized to access %resources

Tags: php, rest, magento, magento2

I am trying to use the Magento 2 rest API, but even when just curl'ing from command line, the only response I get is `Consumer is not authorized to access %resources`

I managed to get a token with

```
curl -X POST "http://magento.dev.blackorange.nl/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token" \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-d '{"username":"adminuser", "password":"adminpass"}'`
```

but when i try

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" "http://magento.dev.blackorange.nl/rest/V1/products"
```

(or any other endpoint) I get the-the `Consumer is not authorized to access %resources` message

Am I missing a step somewhere?

Comment: Did you find a solution? If so, please accept an answer or post your own.

Comment: Unfortunately no solution, we opted to not upgrading to magento 2 and staying with 1.9

Comment: Thanks for your response. Seems to be a bug or obscure configuration problem. After getting this, I tried a fresh install of Magento 2.2 and the error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you are using Magento2 admin username password not any API Username Password With proper roles are assigned to that user , if this does not work 
try changing the ROLE : ALL

to access **GET /V1/products** you need to pass **searchCriteria** parameter its required parameter.

1st you need to call admin/token API 
the token you get from here you need to pass in 2nd API

replace **TOKEN** with your token Key from 1st Call

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer ntfw****avefg***6mil***kysnl3***" "http://magento.dev.blackorange.nl/rest/V1/products"
```

for all REST API Reference :  http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#/

Answer (score 1):

Try it with trimming the token value.
It gets blank space which makes it incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get token of with POSTMAN : **http://your-domin/rest/V1/integration/admin/token**

With admin username password
Example:
**http://your-domin/rest/V1/integration/admin/token**

set Oauth:1.0 same as customer/token

set admin login detail

username : admin | 
password : admin123

And try again with admin token for unauthorized APIs.

Note : This is not good approach because for customer Application it is not secure for just hit API you can try it with admin/token with

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the PHP handler used by Apache on the Magento server. I changed from cgi to suphp and the requests started to work. Interestingly, as mentioned in [Problem with Magento 2 REST authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57028498/problem-with-magento-2-rest-authentication/59530132), POST requests would always work, but GET requests would fail. I have no idea why changing the handler solves the problem. Good luck.